# What's causing background apt network usage?

Tags: debian, apt, raspbian

I have a Raspberry Pi (Raspbian/Debian Bullseye) that's set up with a cellular modem as its only internet-connected network interface. To reduce data costs, I want to restrict Raspbian's network usage to only my app. Letting it run for a few days with `nethogs` inspecting network usage, it seems like something is triggering automatic `apt` updates, consuming around 30KB/day.

I've already disabled and masked `apt-daily.service`, `apt-daily-upgrade.service`, `apt-daily.timer`, and `apt-daily-upgrade.timer`. `cat /var/log/syslog | grep apt` is empty, and `/var/log/apt/*.log` show no activity.

Given the total payload size, it's definitely doing `apt update` in the background, because I can trigger the exact same network footprint with `sudo apt update` manually. How can I find out what's triggering it?

Comment: unattended upgrades?

Comment: `unattended-upgrades` is not installed

Comment: did you check your cron jobs?  e.g. `sudo grep -i 'apt.*update' /etc/crontab /etc/cron*/* /var/spool/cron/crontabs/*`

Answer (score 0):

Found it! It was `packagekit` doing a daily source list update. Stopped and masked the `packagekit` service, then suppressed a complaint on every subsequent `apt` operation that the service is masked by following these instructions: https://medium.com/opsops/how-to-disable-packagekit-f935207044c1